# Bakers semi sweet chocolate bar

Tags: measurements

I feel like a real dummy but I need some help.  I have a recipe that is calling for 8 oz of semi sweet chocolate finely chopped.  I'm thinking that means a semi sweet chocolate  bar chopped up.  I read where a lady said each square is an ounce of chocolate but on the box it says there is 4 ounces  but I bought the box and when I got it home and opened it, there are 8 squares in it.  Why does the box say 4 ounces if each square is an ounce and there are 8 squares?

Comment: Well, if you need 8oz and one box says 4oz, I hope you bought two? Just because *some* chocolate comes in squares of 1oz, there is no *standard* that stipulates *all* chocolates are sold with the same design. Or simply put, the brand you bought has 1/2oz squares.

Comment: "I read where a lady said each square is an ounce of chocolate" might have been correct in her example, but is hardly a reference statement.

Answer (score 9):

Bakers Chocolate *used to* come in 1-ounce squares, but doesn't anymore. This has caused me some confusion (and unexpected recipe results!) in the past, since *decades* of recipes specified chocolate quantities by squares, rather than by ounces.

I have no idea why they made the change. But, the solution/workaround is to go by weight rather than by squares. If a recipe calls for 8 ounces, look at the package and figure out how many packages (or fraction of a package) you'll need -- in this case, two packages. If a recipe calls for squares (e.g. "8 squares"), then keep in mind that used to mean one ounce per square, figure out the weight (8 ounces), and purchase / add to recipe accordingly.

Comment: Possibly to make it easier to break the bar into small pieces for melting.