# Semi-Sweet Chocolate bits

Tags: chocolate

I have a recipe from maybe the 1950's that calls for 1 pkg semi-sweet chocolate  -  I seem to remember a smaller bag than what I find in the stores.  Might this be 
6 ounces it is calling for?   The recipe is for a Chocolate Satin Pie.

Comment: We could probably make an educated guess if you added the whole recipe to your original question...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bakers semi sweet chocolate bar](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/84883/bakers-semi-sweet-chocolate-bar)

Answer (score 1):

A "package" of bittersweet or sent-sweet baking chocolate was historically 8 ounces, as eight 1-ounce squares (or 16 half-ounce half-squares).