# What size were Baker's Chocolate bars when they were first introduced?

Tags: baking, hot-chocolate, vintage-cooking

I have a recipe from my grandmother that calls for a bar of Baker's Chocolate.
What size (weight) were these bars made by Baker's Chocolates when they were first introduced?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bakers semi sweet chocolate bar](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/84883/bakers-semi-sweet-chocolate-bar)

Comment: [This question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/84883/17272) is related, but is specifically about the former size of the *individual squares* rather than a *full bar*.

Answer (score 8):

Bakers Chocolate Bars prior to mid 2013 were 8 ounce bars, after mid 2013 they became a 4 ounce bar.

Comment: https://www.ebay.com/itm/1960s-BAKERS-CHOCOLATE-Box-vintage-baking-/184157356155

Comment: Thank you so much!!!  I knew there had to be a difference