# Older recipe using bakers chocolate asking for 4 squares of chocolate - is that equivalent to current squares?

Tags: substitutions

I have an older recipe that calls for 4 squares of bakers chocolate. Will that be the same as the current squares, or do I need to increase the amount of chocolate?

Comment: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/84886/28879

Comment: Welcome, Laura! I think this question will be closed as duplicate, which in your case is a good thing: We already have the answers you are looking for ;-)